# ASP.NET Forms Auth - Can I get a temporary unique ID before the user is logged in?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using ASP.NET Forms Authentication (Roles, Users, Membership, etc).

In short, I'm looking for something that will give me a unique UserId for users -before- they are logged in or before they create an account.

I would like the user to be able to personalize the site to a certain extent -before- they go about the work if creating an account.  I realize that work would be lost if they clear their cookies.

I store personalized settings in a table with their ASP.NET Auth UserId.  I'm hoping that users get assigned a cookie-based UserId even before they log in and create an account, rather than every "guest" having the same "guest id".

If and when they do create an account or log in I'd have to migrate their saved settings to their "permanent" UserId, but that's ok with me.

I could re-invent something, creating a Guid and storing it in a cookie, but I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel if there's already a mechanism in ASP.NET.

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: Use a Guid. That will be a unique value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Personalization and User Profiles in ASP.NET 2.0 - Handling Anonymous Users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163724.aspx#S6).

> Note that each anonymous user gets a unique anonymous ID the first time they visit a site. This ID is stored persistently in a cookie. Thus, if a second user opens up a browser on the same computer as the first, the second user will be seen by the site as having the same anonymous ID that was issued to the first user.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't find that page searching myself before I posted, but thanks for pointing me at it!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.  There is no user id assigned to anonymous users that you can store in the Profile table.  You will have to create an "AnonymousSettings" table that you store customization information on a per user basis.  You would generate your own cookie with a unique ID (a GUID would be a good choice) and the use that to lookup the anonymous user.

Once the user registers, you can transfer their settings from the anonymous table to the profile settings.

Answer (score -1):

Asp.net Automatically generate SessionID per user. 
You can use SessionID of active user.

**Session.SessionID** returns unique key for user. SessionID stored in Cookies.
 Asp.Net doesn't remove  Session Cookie. After User logged in. So
You can match SessionID and UserId.

Comment: That's wrong.  First, SessionID's can and do get reused.  They're not unique.  Second, a session can be new each time a user accesses the site, so any changes saved with a previous id would not be there the next time the came back.  They *might* be the same session id, but the rules for this are a bit more complex.